# word for when you feel less than fearful, esp. when trying new experiences.

Tags: single-word-requests

Sometimes when you are trying a new experience, you get 'concerned' as to how things will play out when doing anything outside of your comfort zone.

'Butterflies-in-stomach' is part of it but is there any other word which tells/shares the same emotion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[***Apprehensive***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/apprehensive) might be what you are looking for:

> **Apprehensive** (adjective)
>
> Feeling worried about something that you are going to do or that is going to happen:
>
> - I'm very apprehensive about tomorrow's meeting.
> - I've invited a lot
>   of people to the party, but I'm a little apprehensive that no one
>   will come.

Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: To piggyback on @Mick: "consternation," "perturbation," "unease," and simply "nerves" all work just fine. I second "apprehension" as the best, with "consternation" or "anxiety," as second and third, respectively.